# Select all columns from table 1 and one column from table two which is grouped by?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table1

```
id1 name1 address1
1    abc  add1
2    abc  add2
```

and table 2

```
id2 name2 mother_name
1    abc   iii
2    abc   jjj
```

I want to do something like

```
select table1.id1,table1.name1,XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,table1.address1||',')).EXTRACT('//text()), table2.name,
       XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,table2.mother_name||',')).EXTRACT('//text())
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.name1=table2.name2
group by table2.name2;
```

So basically output will be like

```
id1 name1 addr1      name2 xmlagg
1    abc  add1,add2   abc  iii,jjj
```

Also,

What if I want to do a group by for one of the t1 columns too?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `listagg()` in a subquery:

```
select t1.*, xmlagg
from table1 t1 join
     (select name2, listagg(mother_name, ',') within group (order by mother_name) as xmlagg
      from table2 t2
      group by name2
     ) t2
     on t1.name1 = t2.name2;
```

EDIT:

The above query does the aggregation before the join, so it can use `t1.*`.  You can also do it after the join:

```
select t1.name, listagg(mother_name, ',') within group (order by mother_name)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name1 = t2.name2
group by t1.name;
```

This form makes it harder to add additional columns to the `select`, but you can aggregate by anything you like.

Comment: It works ... I have older version of oracle .. so XMLagg works too.

Comment: What if I want to do a group by for one of the t1 columns too?