# Group by matching from another table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, matching

I need to group a list of traffic (redirects) by `client_id`.

The traffic is in one table (`traffic_table`)
The client_id and the different client urls are in another table.

My problem is that the matching needs to be a fuzzy/ LIKE since I don't have a join option. Each client_id can have multiple urls. the client url needs to be matched with the domain column in the traffic table with some sort of LIKE.

I can not get this to show the correct result.

Does somebody have an idea?

Example data:

**Traffic_table:**

```
    domain                     count

www.google.com/dasdasdas        45
google.com/2lkj24j              755
http://www.google.de/42dasdsa   74
www.bing.com/1321               65
http://www.bing.de/1321ds       74
```

**Client_table:**

```
client_id    url 

   1       google.com
   1       google.de 
   2       bing.com 
   2       bing.de
```

Comment: this principal but with a tweek around for not having the option to join directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278277/select-all-columns-from-table-1-and-one-column-from-table-two-which-is-grouped-b/23278417?noredirect=1#comment35632889_23278417

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your problem correctly, in my eyes you want to sum all traffic counts grouped by the client urls. Than you can easily join with like expression:

```
 SELECT c.url,SUM(t.count) FROM client c JOIN traffic t ON t.domain LIKE CONCAT('%',c.url,'%') GROUP BY c.client_id
```

The result with your sample data:

[image: The result with your sample data]

//edit: SELECT c.client_id, SUM(... is better than c.url

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(*) FROM wreams w JOIN categories c ON w.category_id = c.id GROUP BY w.category_id ORDER BY `COUNT(*)` DESC
```

Here is the query I performed. This will get highest results at top also.